# Changed version number on Mac Pro Yosemite and can no longer boot

Tags: macos

A friend of mine offered to download a program for me onto my Mac, but he asked to see what version I'm running beforehand. When he saw that I was running Yosemite 10.10.1 he said I would have to change some things around in terminal for the crack to work. He sent me a link to a video which told me how to change the version number in terminal to 10.5, I did so despite my lack of knowledge on terminal, stupidity at its finest. Almost immediately after, none of my applications were available, not even terminal. I tried restarting my Mac and I hadn't been able to boot since. I can't reinstall OS X because it says the item is temporarily unavailable. Nothing in Disk Utility makes a difference, at least not from what others online have said. I've tried some of the terminal instructions others have posted online, but the commands "sudo" and "nano" cannot be found and that always seems to hinder the process. I ran out of ideas as soon as reinstalling OS X didn't work out. Please, please help me.

Comment: That should be a valuable lesson for you, both in terms of friend selection and in terms of allowing suspect software on to your machine. Take it into an Apple store, let them fix it (they'll probably charge you money for this), and don't be so ... trusting next time. In any case, this is not a suitable question for SO - click on help/help-center at the top of this page.

Comment: Now I understand why they introduced System Integrity Protection...

Comment: adding a link to that video might help to figure out the issue

Comment: I've already considered these things, I know it was a mistake, if it wasn't I wouldn't be asking for help. I'm hoping someone can help me figure this out without me having to go to an Apple Store. Sure last resort I'll take it in, but I'd like to learn something new, I'd like to learn how to fix this.

Comment: If you have cracked software on your machine, the *best* fix is to totally blow it away and start from scratch. Without that, trust in what you have is seriously degraded.

Comment: What do you mean by totally blow it away? Im fine with losing everything I've put onto this computer.

Comment: Take it to the Apple Store. Consider the cost as payment for the vast knowledge you gained about not doing stupid things based on advice and information you don't understand that you got from an idiot friend and some stranger's web video.

Comment: I'm guessing [this process](http://justindaigle.com/blog/2010/02/tutorial-change-mac-os-x-system-version/) is similar to the one you used? And can we assume you don't have a Time Machine backup or similar from before the time you made the change? If yes to both, [this comment](http://justindaigle.com/blog/2010/02/tutorial-change-mac-os-x-system-version/#comment-32207) about fixing it in single user mode *may* help. Or may not.